# How to open console in index.js

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm currently learning javascript on youtube and one of the instructor have console like this:

[image]

He is using visual studio code as text editor and I downloaded  live server as instructor. However, I could only see dubug console or open a live server in a new window in order to reach the console there. I could not open a console like him on the side. Could anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a HTML file with the tag:

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

and open the HTML file in a browser. Then open developer tools and you can see the output in the console.

Answer (score 0):

He is probably using Chrome. ( CMD + Alt + i) OSX (F12) Windows.

Then go to the Console tab.

Answer (score 0):

That is the console from the browser. Start the server and go to server's page on the browser, then use Ctrl + Shift + J (on windows) or Command + Options + J (on Mac) or just right click and open dev tools and select console. To put it on the side there is a button in the top-left corner.

Play around a bit and you'll find it.

Comment: Hi, thank you. But I know how to open one in the browser, I just dont know how to open one in the visual studio code

Comment: Don't know if that's possible but if you want you can open the console in a separate window and put it con the side of Vs code

Answer (score 0):

Create a HTML file and open it in Chrome. Press Ctrl + Shift + I to open developer's tools and open the console tab.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I know that. I mean is there a way to open a console inside the visual studio code like the attached pic? I used atoms before and it seems like it had "console" but there's always github erros popping out. Thats why I started using visual studio code, but I didn't find a console tab.